# Saving program image in guile

Tags: scheme, guile

I've heard that most lisps support saving image of running program into file. Does guile  support this?

Comment: Do you mean, saving a continuation to a file?  I think that would clarify the question for people reading it.

Comment: I do not think he means saving a continuation to a file, rather he wants to define functions in a repl, save the state of the interpreter, close the interpreter and reboot the machine or whatever, then open the repl, and load the image file, restoring the repl to how it was before he quit.

Comment: Yes! That is what I wanted. I've found this feature in scm scheme interpreter, but not in guile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that interoperating with other languages is pretty integral to what Guile is, and so there is a lot of state in an interpreter image that is opaque to Guile itself.  I know Guile best from working with it as the scheme interpreter built into gEDA, so can you imagine having to save not just all the CONSes, but also all the X windows that gschem might have open?  It just isn't feasible to do reliably from within Guile.  (And I'm not sure it would be a good idea to implement save-image-to-file even in "limited" cases.)

That said, ultimately you can save the program state, but since the program boundaries are so porous, what with file descriptors and memory maps leaking out of every pore, you soon realize that you have to save the entire computer's state.  This is done though, in the form of the "hibernate" power-saving mode!  I realize, too, that that isn't what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

[SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/Saving-a-Core-Image.html), an implementation of Common Lisp, can do this. (Also see this [short SBCL tutorial](http://mikael.jansson.be/log/freezing-lisp-in-time)). If you are interested in exploring other dynamic languages that can save and restore the system state (including continuations, open file descriptors or whatever), have a look at [Squeak](http://www.squeak.org/).